# Accessing Service Layer from Controller in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I previously had a controller that had code like this:

```
public ActionResult Method(int Id)
        {
            var foo = doThis(Id)
            return View("Error");
        }
```

doThis() is a method that exists in the controller, and performs some logic.  I'm now trying to relocate all business logic to a Services project that contains a bunch of classes.

To start I added a class library Project.Services and then added a class FooServices which contains the following:

```
namespace Project.Services
{
    class FooServices
    {
        public List<Bar> doThis(int Id)
        {
            //Do stuff
            return parentSets;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a reference to this project from my MVC project, and a reference from this Services project to my data model project, but I'm not sure how to proceed now.  How can I access these methods from controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I access these methods from controllers?

In order to access an instance method you need an instance of the object:

```
public ActionResult Method(int Id)
{
    var foo = new FooServices().doThis(Id)
    return View("Error");
}
```

Of course by doing this you are now strongly coupling your controller logic with a specific implementation of your service making it very difficult to unit test your controllers in isolation.

So to weaken the coupling start by introducing an abstraction:

```
public interface IFooServices
{
    List<Bar> DoThis(int id)
}
```

and then have your service layer implement this interface:

```
public class FooServices: IFooServices
{
    public List<Bar> DoThis(int id)
    {
        //Do stuff
        return parentSets;
    }
}
```

Alright, now your controller could work with this abstraction:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly IFooServices service;
    public HomeController(IFooServices service)
    {
        this.sevrice = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Method(int id)
    {
        var foo = this.service.DoThis(id)
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Great, at this stage we really have a weak coupling between your controller and the service layer. All that's left now is to configure your favorite dependency Injection framework to inject the specific service into your controller.

Comment: Thank you Very well explained.

Comment: I have a following situation, In my project there are ten controllers and ten service classes with business logic involved in each service class. Also I have reference data ( country, vendor, merchant and product names) which I need in all the controllers. Since I need to get the reference data in all the controllers
Shall I write these get methods in all the ten service classes (redundant) or do I need to create a service class(there is no business logic) name it "refservice" with all the get methods?
What is the best approach?